# java regex for alpha and spaces is including [ ] \

Tags: java, regex

This is my regex for my JTextField to not be longer than x characters and to not include anything other than letters or spaces.  **For some reason it is allowing [ ] and \ characters.**  This is driving me crazy.  Is my regex wrong??

```
package com.jayavon.game.helper;

import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class CharacterNameCreationDocument extends PlainDocument {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int limit;

    public CharacterNameCreationDocument(int limit) {
        super();
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public void insertString(int offset, String  str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (str == null || (getLength() + str.length()) > limit || !str.matches("[a-zA-z\\s]*")){
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            return;
        } else {
            super.insertString(offset, str, attr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so for example you want only string with length of 3, it should only macth `hel`, `y y`, and not `c[ss`, `kkkk`?

Comment: yes that would be correct, currently I call it with 20 and it allows me to enter [ ]  or \

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a typo in your regex:

```
"[a-zA-z\\s]*"
```

`[A-z]` matches all the uppercase and lowercase letters **plus** `[`, `]`, `^`, `_`, backslash and backtick, whose code points happen to lie between `Z` and `a`.

Also, I agree with @Ωmega that you probably should be using an actual space character instead of `\s`:

```
"[a-zA-Z ]*"
```

The anchors (`^` and `$`) aren't necessary since you're using the `matches()` method, which automatically anchors the match at both ends.  They don't hurt anything though, and they do help communicate your intent.

Answer (score 7):

You should use regex pattern

```
^[a-zA-Z\\s]*$
```

where `^` is start of string and `$` represents end of string.

---

You can also extend such regex to check the string size. Let's say if you want allow minimum `5` characters and maximum `20` characters

```
^[a-zA-Z\\s]{5,20}$
```

---

However, because whitespace `\\s` can be not just space-bar character, but also other charactes, such as new-line, tab, etc., you may want to limit this just to real space-bar characters using

```
 ^[a-zA-Z ]{5,20}$
```

---

Additionaly, you might want to limit multiple space characters to be used in sequence. If so, use

```
^(?!.* {2,})[a-zA-Z ]{5,20}$`
```

---

You might want string always to start and end with non-space characters. To add such feature go with

```
^(?=.{5,20}$)(?!.* {2,})[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z]$
```

Comment: it allows me to enter [ ] or \ which I don't want

Comment: @JayAvon Are you certain your `(getLength() + str.length()) > limit` logic is correct? Ωmega's pattern would not allow such characters to be entered.

Answer (score 1):

reformat your regex into this:

```
^[A-Za-z\\s]{0,3}$
```

just change 3 to your desired length.

Comment: it allows me to enter [ ] or \ which I don't want ALSO the 0,3 was not part of the question, i am using the document for that, which works great